# Where is DNS servers config file

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, dns, gui

Im using Pop OS and I changed my DNS via settings GUI and clicking apply.

I'm wondering if there is a config file for it, so I can change it via cli and maybe it even works in ubuntu server.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux) –

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop uses *NetworkManager* to control networking, where as Ubuntu Server by default uses *netplan* so they differ, however as you've already been told Pop OS is not Ubuntu, nor *flavor* of Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought Pop Os is based on Ubuntu.

Comment: It's based on Ubuntu yes, however it's not Ubuntu nor *flavor* of Ubuntu and is still a different system. Pop OS use some features that Ubuntu considers *testing* grade (ie. not yet *stable* and thus not fit for production systems) as System76 build their OS for products they sell and the later features they deem necessary. Pop also have different security standards which allow them to be *first* (beofre testing standards for Ubuntu have been met) etc.. ie. it's a different system (even if much of Pop is identical to Ubuntu, it's still not all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to look at /etc/resolv.conf ?

Check or change "nameserver"

Comment: ```nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad```

I have changed it to 1.1.1.1 so this doesn't appear to be the nameserver config file.

Comment: But 1.1.1.1 is a valid DNS server. I think it's from Cloudflare

Comment: I know that but 1.1.1.1 should appear that instead of 127.0.0.53.

Comment: try nslookup

My resolv.conf:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
options edns0 trust-ad
search home

nslookup:
~$ nslookup
> google.com
Server:  8.8.8.8
Address:         8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: google.com
Address: 142.250.79.14
Name: google.com
Address: 2800:3f0:4004:80a::200e

Comment: In fact... my OS is Ubuntu 20. I can search for POP Os configs

Comment: Take a look at /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections

Add to your connection:
[ipv4]
dns=1.1.1.1;8.8.8.8;9.9.9.9;

Comment: Oh yes, I see it at `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. Thank you